# Can't restore privateKey RSA

Tags: java, security, encryption, rsa, private-key

I have this issue about java cryptography.
I take a password from the user then I product a private key and a public key.From the public key I create the cipher and then I store the private key and the cipher.

Then from my second application I read the password again from the user , the cipher file and the private key and then I try to match the password with the decryption of the cipher and the private Key.

---

My first application:

```
private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] inpBytes, PublicKey key,
String xform) throws Exception {
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(xform);
 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
return cipher.doFinal(inpBytes);
}


 String xform = "RSA";
 // Generate a key-pair
 KeyPairGenerator kpg = null;
        try {
            kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Efarmogi_1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
 kpg.initialize(512); // 512 is the keysize.
 KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
 /create public and private key
 PublicKey pubk = kp.getPublic();
 PrivateKey prvk = kp.getPrivate();

 //password from user 
 String password = T_Password.getText();

byte[] dataBytes = password.getBytes();
//create cipher
byte[] encBytes = null;
        try {
            encBytes = encrypt(dataBytes, pubk, xform);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Efarmogi_1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

//storing
//cipher
  FileOutputStream cipher = null;
        try {
            cipher = new FileOutputStream( "Xrhstes\\"+T_Username.getText()+"\\hash_"+T_Username.getText());

            cipher.write(encBytes);//write with bytes

            cipher.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Efarmogi_1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

//private key
 byte[] key2 = prvk.getEncoded();
            FileOutputStream keyfos2 = null;
        try {
            keyfos2 = new FileOutputStream("Xrhstes\\"+T_Username.getText()+"\\private_"+ T_Username.getText()+".pem");

            keyfos2.write(key2);

            keyfos2.close();
```

---

and this is the second application:

```
   private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] inpBytes, PrivateKey key,String xform) throws Exception{
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(xform);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
return cipher.doFinal(inpBytes);
}

//fetch private key           
byte[] prvk1 = new byte[(int)new File("C:\\...\\"+T_Username.getText()+"\\private_"+ T_Username.getText()).length()]; 

//make it from bytes to private key
  KeyFactory kf= KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
  PrivateKey prvk=kf.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(prvk1));

//fetch cipher
 byte[] encBytes = new byte[(int)new File("C:\\...\\"+T_Username.getText()+"\\hash_"+ T_Username.getText()).length()]; 

//decrypt with our password given from user
    String xform = "RSA";

         byte[] decBytes = decrypt(encBytes,prvk, xform);

        boolean expected = java.util.Arrays.equals(password, decBytes);
        System.out.println("Test " + (expected ? "SUCCEEDED!" : "FAILED!"));
```

---

My issue is when I try to retransform the bytes saved , back to privateKey I get multiple errors that key type is invalid(problem starts at decoding PKCS8EncodedKeySpec it is noted that KeySpec is invalid).I tried numerous ways but still the same,could someone guide me where is my mistake ?  thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

With the following lines:

```
byte[] prvk1 = new byte[(int)new File("C:\\...\\"+T_Username.getText()+"\\private_"+ T_Username.getText()).length()];
```

and

```
byte[] encBytes = new byte[(int)new File("C:\\...\\"+T_Username.getText()+"\\hash_"+ T_Username.getText()).length()];
```

You actually create two empty byte arrays. You only indicate the size of the array using `File.length()`, which obviously is not correct. Try again after actually reading the files, e.g. using the [`readAllBytes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-) method (requires Java 8 or higher).